# select с вызовом внешнего файла

Tags: javascript, html

Есть обычный select:

```
<select>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

Возможно ли как то вынести значения во внешний файл, например select.html, чтобы при открытии списка - подгружались option'ы с этого файла? Может на javasript есть какое то решение? Уже весь интернет обыскал, ничего не нашел.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно загрузить с сервера [json](https://api.myjson.com/bins/jzm1v) и склеить из него.

```js
let toOption = data => `<option value="${data}">${data}</option>`;

select.onclick = e => fetch('https://api.myjson.com/bins/jzm1v')
  .then(resp => resp.json())
  .then(data => {
    select.onclick = null;
    select.innerHTML = data.map(toOption).join('')
    select.blur();
  })
```

```html
<select id=select><option>click to load</option></select>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! А как подгрузить данные только при открытии списка? То есть при нажатии на него. Сейчас подгружаются данные сразу.

Comment: @Stop-TussiN сейчас дополню ответ

Comment: Благодарю, отлично работает :)

Comment: @Stop-TussiN только надо после загрузки слушатель удалить

Comment: не пойму как вставить ваш код json. Вставляю его в <script> </sript> и ничего не работает. Как его вставить?

Comment: @Stop-TussiN он должен лежать в файле.json на сервере рядом с html-кой

Comment: А как тогда в html коде его вызвать? Я про код, который начинается с let toOption.. Про файл json то я понял, а про код не пойму

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97576/discussion-between-stranger-in-the-q-and-stop-tussin).

Answer (score 1):

Вариант на jquery.
В options.text каждый option на новой строке. Значение от название отделены знаком равно (=).

```
$('select').click(function(event) {
    if($(this).text()==''){
        $select = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            url: 'options.text',
            dataType: 'text',
        })
        .done(function(options) {
            options = options.split('\n');
            for( opt in options ){
                option = options[opt].split('=');
                $select.append( '<option value='+option[0]+'>'+option[1]+'</option>' );
            }
        });
    }
});
```